# How to insert a line break in perl after the first + that appears in text

Tags: regex, perl, search, replace

for example

```
*aabc aacb  aavg +gf avb avb abf
```

Should be

```
*aabc aacb  aavg 
+gf avb avb abf
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this more 'before' the first `+` appears?

Comment: Does `"in text"` mean "on every line in the file" or "in file"?

Answer (score 7):

Use a substitution:

```
my $text =  '*aabc aacb  aavg +gf avb avb abf';
$text    =~ s/\+/\n+/;
print $text;
```

`+` must be backslashed to lose its special meaning, `\n` is a newline.

Comment: Alternatively, use a lookahead assertion: `s{(?=\+)}{\n};`

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str = "*aabc aacb  aavg +gf avb avb abf";
$str =~ s/\+/\n\+/;
print $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> echo "abcd +gkj +bcd" | perl -pe 's/\+/\n\+/'
abcd 
+gkj +bcd
```